# In Android, how do I show a single notification when handling multiple intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have an `BroadcastReceiver` for handling new or modified applications:

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageHandler" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When an intent is received, I show a notification containing some of the package information. My problem is that when I add a new app, for example while debugging, two intents are received from `PackageHandler`, and thus two notifications are displayed. To illustrate, this `BroadcastReceiver`, which handles the intents discussed, will show a *logcat* entry every time the intent is sent, which is twice when I update an app:

```
public class PackageHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("", "Intent Received: " + intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
            Log.i("Intent Received", intent.getAction());
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
            Log.i("Intent Received", intent.getAction());
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED)) {
            Log.i("Intent Received", intent.getAction());
        }

    }//onReceive
}//PackageHandler
```

However I need a solution that keeps track of having already showed a log message (from handling a different intents). From a notifications view point, I could also optionally remove extra notifications after they are displayed. Does anyone have a working solution? Note that I am supporting API 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with works really nicely, but I had a tough time figuring it out. In a separate class, which contains many *static* variables (let's call it *S.java*), I created an `integer` called *pid*. Then I added to my `BroadcastReceiver` to include a `synchronized` method that compares process PIDs and decides if one is a match. Most of the time, only one of the `intents` are received, however I have had up to two, which this protects against. I have never had three `intent` calls to this receiver at one time, so this is not designed to handle that many. The new code (adding to the above code) is as follows:

```
public class PackageHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!getPID()) {
            return;
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
            Log.i("Intent Received", intent.getAction());
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
            Log.i("Intent Received", intent.getAction());
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED)) {
            Log.i("Intent Received", intent.getAction());
        }
    }//onReceive

    public synchronized boolean getPID() {
       ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
       List<RunningAppProcessInfo> raps = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
       int pid = 0;
       for (RunningAppProcessInfo rap : raps) {
           if (rap.processName.equals("com.example.android")) {//change to your package
               pid = rap.pid;
               break;
           }
       }
       if (pid == S.pid) {
           Log.i("", "PIDs match");
           S.pid = 0;
           return false;
       }
       else {
           Log.i("", "Non-Matching PIDs");
           S.pid = pid;
           return true;
       }
   }//getPID

}//PackageHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

If we use the same unique id in [NotificationManager.notify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29), the new notification will replace the older notification.

Comment: the problem here is that I keep track of which IDs I have used so I don't overwrite notifications. This is similar to how the Android Market keeps a different notification visible for each downloaded app.

Comment: you could use intent.getdata().getSchemeSpecificPart() where you get the package and store it in a SharedPreferences  and check for duplicates